# Lightning Web Component Fetch Error CPS URL is Whitelisted

Tags: lightning-web-components

I am having issues with using `fetch` with my LWC

My endpoint is properly white-labeled in CSP settings.

## JavaScript:

```
@track ohtData = [];

  connectedCallback() {
    console.log("connected callback is called");
    fetch(
      "https://thisisasamplecallout/api/accounts/1",
      { method: "GET", redirect: "follow", mode: "cors" }
    )
      .then(res => res.json())
      .then(data => {
        this.ohtData = data;
        console.log(this.ohtData);
      })
      .catch(error => console.log("error", error));
  }
```

## Error Message:

[image]

In the in my Chrome dev console no network request is made.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The mode must be `mode: "no-cors"` as per the error message is stated.